Pandas - Filter - TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
I am exploring Pandas filter and while doing so I came across this error while using the below query
df2.filter(like = ['Republic','United'], axis=0 )

How do I provide a list in Like parameter in filter?
I tried giving a data without list, it was working but the data with a list is not working.
I was expecting a filter result with the items mentioned in the list

You might want to try using items in place of like
df2.filter(items=['Republic', 'United'], axis=0 )


items: list-like - Keep labels from axis which are in items.
like: str - Keep labels from axis for which “like in label == True”.

See documentation for filter.

As you figured out the problem here is that the argument like in pd.DataFrame.filter() is expecting a string as in: WHERE table.columnName LIKE 'something'. (SQL Syntax)
There is no way to pass a list in the like field, however you can try concatenating different filtered dfs. Here is an example:
filtered_dfs = []
filters = ['Republic', 'United']

for f in filters:
    tmp_df = df2.filter(like= f, axis= 0)
    filtered_dfs.append(tmp_df)

filtered = pd.concat(filtered_dfs)

I didn't try the code but let me know if it works!
